# make UIToolbar items evenly distributed over the toolbar

Tags: ios

here is my code

```objectivec
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, 44)];
self.toolbar = boolbar;
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

NSMutableArray *arrayM = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *titles = @[@"title0", @"title1", @"title2", @"title3"];
for (int i = 0; i < titles.count; i++) {
    [arrayM addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace] target:nil action:nil];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(256)/255.0 green:arc4random_uniform(256)/255.0 blue:arc4random_uniform(256)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [button setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [arrayM addObject:item];
}
[arrayM addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace] target:nil action:nil];
toolbar.items = arrayM;
```

and the result is shown in the following screenshot
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48YIG.png)

The clickable range of the button is too small, and I don't want to set a fixed size for the button because the button titles will be different. I want each button to be evenly distributed on the toolbar, but I can't find a suitable way

I tried using all the items provided by the system but nothing worked

[all UIBarButtonSystemItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejoqi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't provide a way to distribute your UIToolbar items evenly, but you can get around this with a few tricks. This is done using a custom class that inherits from UIToolbar, as follows:

```objectivec
@interface MYToolbar : UIToolbar

@end

@implementation MYToolbar
- (void)setItemsDistributionFillEqually:(UIView *)view {
    [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIStackView class]]) {
            [(UIStackView *)obj setDistribution:UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually];
            *stop = YES;
        }
        [self setItemsDistributionFillEqually:obj];
    }];
}
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setItemsDistributionFillEqually:self];
}
@end
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?